# How to read something from a file with C# and use it with HTML codes on ASP.NET page?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, google-maps

I'm doing a school project, I need to make a simple web site, add google maps on it, read, lets say, 100 diffrent addresses from a text file and show those locations on google maps with markers.

Now I'm trying to add google maps to my ASP.net page with javascript which I saw on google maps tutorials. And there's that problem which I have to convert adresses to coordinates. So for that I'm using

```
function addAddressToMap(response) {
    if (!response || response.Status.code != 200) {
        alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode that address");
    } 
    else {
        place = response.Placemark[0];
        point = new GLatLng(place.Point.coordinates[1],place.Point.coordinates[0]);
        marker = new GMarker(point);
        map.addOverlay(marker);
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(place.address + '<br>' + '<b>Country code:</b> ' + place.AddressDetails.Country.CountryNameCode);
    }
}

// showLocation() is called when you click on the Search button
// in the form.  It geocodes the address entered into the form
// and adds a marker to the map at that location.
function showLocation() {
    var address = "izmit";
    var address2 = "ağrı";
    geocoder.getLocations(address, addAddressToMap);
    geocoder.getLocations(address2, addAddressToMap);
}
```

these functions and they are working fine. But my problem here is, I need to get these address informations from a text file. But to get them, I need to use a few diffrent codes. And I want to make it on the server side with C# codes. But I don't know how to write some codes on server side and then return something to HTML side as address. I hope you understand. Thank you for your helps.

#### Update:

```
Server code:

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("Skills", "'asa'");
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("Skills", "'bell'");
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("Skills", "'C'");
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("Skills", "'C++'");
    }
}

Client side:

function showLocation()
{
    var address = "izmit";
    var address2 = "ağrı";
    geocoder.getLocations(Skills[0], addAddressToMap);
}
```

Now if I use "asa" instead of  Skills[0] it will show the location and mark, but with Skills[0] it's not working. And thank you for your answer that was what I'm looking for.

even if I try var MyValue = Skills[0]; and then use MyValue instead of Skills[0] it's still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to create an array on the server side and read it in the client.

See [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/92600/How-to-pass-ASP-NET-server-side-array-to-client-si) for a tutorial on how to pass an array from the server to the client.

Basically, you want to use the [ClientScriptManager.RegisterArrayDeclaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerarraydeclaration.aspx) method to add values to the array.

You can then easily read it in javascript.

**Server Side:**

```
string arrayName = "MyArray";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration(arrayName , "'value1'");
Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration(arrayName , "'value2'");
```

**Javascript on Client Side:**

```
function readArray() 
{
            for (var i = 0; i < MyArray.length; i++) 
            {
                //Reading Element From Array
                var myValue = MyArray[i];
            }
 }
```

Comment: It was too long and I tried to add with with Another Answer, it's on top of your answer.

Comment: Alright sorry about that, I tried to edit my post but somehow it was already updated. Thank you again.

Comment: I'm guessing your code runs before the onload event? Try adding this code to your javascript, it should show a messagebox with "asa": **window.onload = function () { alert(Skills[0]); };**

Comment: Yes my code runs before the onload event. I mean, first my script with google maps and some functions and then the <body onload="initialize()"> code comes at the bottom, and when I paste window.onload = function () { alert(Skills[0]); }; on my script, nothin happens.

Comment: I just tested it on a small side-project and it works as expected. Pasting the above code works fine and putting the *window.onload* line inside a <script> tag does popup an alert with 'asa'. So I recommend trying this in a side project and see if it works there - just to make sure there isn't some other problem with your current code. Also, try just writing *alert(Skills[0]);* inside your initalize() function

Comment: When I add just alert("something"); to my initalize(), it pops up an alert like you said. But when I put Skills[0] in it I mean alert(Skills[0]); it is not working. Maybe my C# code is wrong. Interesting.

Comment: Hey, are you using runat="server" anywhere of your small side-project?

Comment: In the javascript?? No... The Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration creates the following in the html:


    <script type="text/javascript">  
    //<![CDATA[  
    var Skills =  new Array('asa', 'bell', 'C', 'C++');  
    //]]>  
    </script>